# how to restart activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a MainActivity which has a navigation drawer.
 If I select an item in the navigation drawer, it launches a dialog fragment FragmentA. Now, if I change a few things in FragmentA, I want MainActivity to reflect the new changes once FragmentA is dismissed. What is the best way to restart MainActivity from FragmentA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I think FragmentA is a DialogFragment. At least i assume it.

You can override onDestroy method in FragmentA and write

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).refreshUI();
```

We basicly, casted activity instance to our activity for letting us call our method that you can refresh ui.

An dirty way is,
You can also write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

By this way, we started our activity again and killed the one which is in backstack. I assume your datas is hold from another class which like singleton. Otherwise you lose them or you can use first method.

Good luck there.

Comment: if I use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, the previous instance is still not killed. If I press the back button, I get one more instance of the same activity

Comment: Can you try to add getActivity().finish(); then call Intent intent = new Intent(getContext, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Did get you get success?

Answer (score 23):

use this code

```
getActivity().recreate();
```